# How should a C library alert the user to bad input, and other intro library concerns

Tags: c, error-handling, shared-libraries, errno

I am writing a small, C shared library, with a fairly basic set of tasks.

The reason I am writing it is that it's part of an interview process. It is expected that people attempting this exercise are junior/intro developers.

I am fairly new to C and have completed the exercise handily, in the specified environment, but I have never built a library before. Since my methods will be called from inside another program, how should I deal with faulty user input?

I am allowed to ask questions and asked one about dealing with this facet explicitly, but received the reply that it is up to the candidate to choose how to deal with errors.

I have read some things about using errno, some good, some bad. Is it standard to report errors using this macro?

I am starting to think about things like portability, but part of the assignment is to use a certain version of Linux and to use the gcc compiler. I think as long as I make a reasonable attempt to make my solution portable, I will be fine.

Are there other things a newb trying to write a library should think about?

Comment: Using `errno` has a problem; it means you can't report errors that aren't already standard system errors.  Often they're sufficient, but if you're compiling regexes, for example, the errors available from `<errno.h>` are mostly not appropriate for the possible regex errors — reporting `EINVAL` for everything that's wrong isn't very helpful.  Also note that no standard library function in either standard C or standard POSIX ever sets `errno` to zero.  You should be careful if you do that in your code:  `int old_errno = errno; errno = 0; …your code…; if (errno == 0) errno = old_errno;` is OK.

Comment: C does not support _methods_, only _functions_

Comment: Jonathan Leffler - that's everything I'm not supposed to do. So can you tell me a reasonable approach to handling user input? Let's use an example of a library only accepting uppercase letters. A user gives a lower case letter or letters. What is a standard method of dealing with bad input?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

`errno` is the most useful method in the standard library for error reporting. `string.h` also defines a helpful function called `strerror` that will transform the error code to a string. Here's a sample function you can use to report errors.

```
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>

void error_quit(char *message)
{
    int errcode = errno;
    fprintf(stderr,"Error at %s: %s\n",message,strerror(errcode));
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
```

Call this setting `message` to whatever error reporting message you want. For example, if you want to check if `read` fails (helpful for checking user input):

```
int n = read(fd,buf,sizeof(buf));
if (n <= 0)
    error_quit("read");
```

It will give the user descriptive information about why `read` failed. Any problems with the user input will be displayed.

## There's also a *very* useful macro for Windows.

```
#define PERR(bSuccess, api) {if(!(bSuccess)) printf("%s: Error %d from %s on line %d\n", __FILE__, (int) GetLastError(), api, (int) __LINE__);}
```

Comment: I like how your implementation doesn't alter errno. I'm not sure I can use this, however. All of my methods simply convert strings to other data types, do something with them, then give them back to the user. I think maybe I'm over thinking this. 

Perhaps I should just document my library well and give the user back their faulty input and a short message on why it's bad.

Comment: Writing a function like the above clearly indicates to you interviewers that you don't know `perror` exists. It also indicates that you don't know how to properly name your functions - A function that's named "`...quit`" and doesn't has a wrong name.

Comment: That code will fail with multithreading. There is just no synchronisation betwenn threads and `errno` is thread local. And the error output stream is `stderr`.

Comment: @tofro Thank you for pointing those things out. I forgot to add the `exit` at the end of my function and I have fixed that. `perror` is only really helpful to the developer, as it does not give any information about what failed and where. It only prints the error.

Comment: @Olaf Thank you for pointing out the `stderr` problem, I messed up while typing that. I apologize to everyone who had to see that terrible code. I was very tired when I answered the question... But I don't think AspiringCodeMonkey ever stated that he needed multithreading and I think a 'newb' will be fine using this function. It's not meant for operating systems, it just helps with basic programming.

Comment: @MDXF Your man pages seem to be broken - `perror` does the exact same thing your function does, except exiting.

Comment: Problem is, this does not answer the question (which itself is too broad and/or opinion based).

Comment: @Olaf except... it does answer the question because it was accepted as the answer.

Comment: @MDXF: From an objective viewpoint, it does not. It shows one way to **report** an error, but not how the library should handle this (see the rest of my comment). From the viewpoint of a user lacking experience: I will not comment about that...

Comment: @Olaf I'm just trying to help out in the simplest and least confusing way. I didn't want to overload anyone with too much code or information. I gave him the base of what he asked for.

Comment: MDXF - It seems like you're capable of reading the context of a question. So thanks for providing an answer that is completely suitable for what I asked.

@else: The question is general for a reason. I wanted discussion about error reporting for simple cases, within the scope of a newb library. Instead of offering resources or insight, there seems to be a lot of "don't do this" vs "hey, read this," or "a better case practice is x." You might all be good developers but you have a lot to learn about teaching, which is typically associated with good leadership.